# Can I prove that $A\Rightarrow (B\wedge C)$ by proving that $\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be propositional variables. I need to prove a statement of the form $A\Rightarrow (B\wedge C)$ and I’m thinking of proving it by showing the equivalent contrapositive statement
$$\neg(B\wedge C)\Rightarrow \neg A$$
Specifically, I’m thinking of simply showing that
$$\neg B\Rightarrow \neg A$$
However, I’m not 100% sure my approach is correct. My question is: **can I prove that $A\Rightarrow(B\wedge C)$ by proving $\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A$?** My attempt at answering my own question is below.

**Statement**: $(\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A)\Rightarrow(A\Rightarrow(B\wedge C))$

**Proof**:
Suppose that
$$\neg (B\wedge C)\Rightarrow \neg A$$
Because
$$\neg B\Rightarrow\neg(B\wedge C)$$
it follows that
$$\neg B\Rightarrow \neg A$$

**EDIT**: I understand from the answers that my reasoning is false. Suppose nonetheless that I still want I to show
$$\neg(B\wedge C)\Rightarrow \neg A$$
How do I do it?

Comment: $(\neg B)\implies (\neg A)$ is equivalent to $A\implies B$.  Obviously $A\implies B$ does not imply $A\implies (B\land C).$

Comment: I want to prove that if someone is drinking in my bar ($A$) then they are over 18 ($B$) and have an ID ($C$). You say  ”I've proved that everyone under 18 is not in the bar ($\lnot B \implies\lnot A$). “That's a start,” I reply. ”But how does it help with the ID requirement?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Re: your first question: unfortunately, your suggestion is invalid. With the counterexample $(A,B,C)=(\text{True, True, False}),$ $$\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A$$ is true but $$\neg(B\wedge C)\Rightarrow\neg A$$ false.
2. Your last section is a proof of $$(¬(B ∧ C) \Rightarrow¬A) \Rightarrow(¬B \Rightarrow ¬A),$$ rather than a proof of $$(\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A)\Rightarrow(A\Rightarrow(B\wedge C)).$$

   While the latter is *not* logically true (my above counterexample shows that it can be false), the former is a tautology, i.e., *is* logically true.

---

**Addendum**

> **EDIT**: I understand from the answers that my reasoning is false. Suppose nonetheless that I still want I to show $$\neg(B\wedge C)\Rightarrow \neg A$$ How do I do it?

Remember, you are proving a statement of this ***form***, not the proposition as it currently stands. For example, does $B$ stand for $\exists x{\in}\mathbb Z\;x^2=8,$ or does it symbolise a compound proposition? That informs your proof strategy.

Comment: Thank you for your revisions and addendum. Suppose that I want to prove a statement of the form $\neg(B\wedge C)\Rightarrow\neg A$. Can I proceed by showing (i) $\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A$ and (ii) $\neg C\Rightarrow\neg A$ independently? Or should I proceed by showing that $\neg B\vee\neg C\Rightarrow\neg A$? Or would both be valid approaches?

Comment: @Héctor Yes both are valid approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are true while $C$ is false, then $\lnot B\to\lnot A$ is true and $\lnot (B\land C)$ is true, meaning $\lnot (B\land C)\to \lnot A$ is false; a true statement cannot imply a false statement.